# variable sound in flex

Tags: xml, variables, apache-flex, audio

I have Flex mobile application with two views:
**viewONE** has `s:list` component, so when the user clicks an item on the list then **viewTWO** is called with the details of the selected item: It shows images and text pulled from **XML** file - and it all works perfectly however not with sound. loading sounds from XML file doesn't work.. so when I do `[@Embed(source="{data.sound}")]` it doesn't work.
is there any way around this? Or do I have to create 20 different views for my 20 items and do `[@Embed(source="sound1.mp3")]` and so on?

Answer (score 0):

You are thinking in a wrong way. Use a class ( or a singleton) to play sounds. Also embed all sounds in that class.

for ex:

```
class MySoundManager
{

    [Embed(.....)]
    public static var SOUND_1:Class;

    [Embed(.....)]
    public static var SOUND_2:Class;

    //  ... sound 3 and so on

    // use static variables
    private static var soundCh:SoundChannel /// ....


    public static function playSound(theSound:Class):void
    {
         //here put the logic for stopping any running sound and start playing "theSound"
    }
}
```

USAGE:

```
// in any of your views, for ex for playing 1st sound
MySoundManager.playSound(MySoundManager.SOUND_1);
```

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for reply.. I am obviously only learning this, so I did't quite get it... sorry for being noob. I will have a PLAY button on the viewTWO, I would need that button to play the sound related to the item that user chosen from the list (so I don't know which sound that going to be).. what "source" do I give to that button to play?